# Filter table rows based on input intervals

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to filter all tables rows while the user is typing in an input field.
The filter is based on a width value that is provided by the user through an input field of type number.

All the input fields ahs a min and max value.

I want to hide all the rows that its input field is not within the range given by the user.

Example:

The user inputs a width of 210cm.
Only one row contains an input field with the min="180" and max="220"
All the other rows should be hidden except for the one within the range.

This almost works for me but only the first row is matching the users input regardless of the width he provides.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

I expect all the other rows that contains a input field () that is not within the given range to get hidden

```js
$('input[name="user_width"]').on("keyup", function() {
  user_width = parseInt($(this).val())

  $(".product_types tr").filter(function() {
    var min_value = parseInt($(this).find("input").attr('min'))
    var max_value = parseInt($(this).find("input").attr('max'))

    if (user_width > min_value && user_width < max_value) {
      $(this).siblings().hide()
    } else if (!user_width) {
      $(this).siblings().show()
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="user_width"> 
<table class="product_types">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td>
        <input type="radio" min="0" max="100">
        <span>row1</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td>
        <input type="radio" min="101" max="220">
        <span>row2</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td>
        <input type="radio" min="221" max="290">
        <span>row3</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `5`: It matches the first range -> hides all other ranges; `50`: matches first range -> hides all other ranges; `500` -> matches none of the ranges but is also not falsy and does nothing. And this will be the case for every number you enter (unless you use copy&paste)

Comment: I dont really understand @Andreas

Comment: Can enyone help please?